# How to call listener class in robot.api?

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a bunch of testsuites which are executed using robot.api.

For Example,

```
from robot.api import TestSuite,ResultWriter
tc_dict = {
            'test case #1' : 'Passed'
            'test case #2' : 'Failed'
           }
suite = TestSuite('tests_with_listener.robot')
for k,v in tc_dict.items():
    test = suite.tests.create(k)
    test.keywords.create('should be equal',args=(tc_dict[k],'Passed'))
result = suite.run(output=xml_fpath)
```

Is there any way in robot.api by which we can execute the following code?

`robot -b debug.txt --listener <ListenerLibrary> tests_with_listener.robot`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after going through robot framework source code I was able to get an answer. The solution is simple but it's not well-documented in robot.api docs.

From RF source code's `run(settings=None, **options)` method from TestSuite class

> If `options` are used, their names are the same as long command line
>           options except without hyphens, and they also have the same semantics.
>           Options that can be given on the command line multiple times can be
>           passed as lists like `variable=['VAR1:value1', 'VAR2:value2']`.
>           If such an option is used only once, it can be given also as a single
>           string like `variable='VAR:value'`.

```
from robot.api import TestSuite,ResultWriter
tc_dict = {
            'test case #1' : 'Passed'
            'test case #2' : 'Failed'
           }
suite = TestSuite('tests_with_listener.robot')
for k,v in tc_dict.items():
    test = suite.tests.create(k)
    test.keywords.create('should be equal',args=(tc_dict[k],'Passed'))
result = suite.run(xunit=xunit_fpath,report=html_fpath,log=log_fpath,listener='AllureReportLibrary.AllureListener')
```

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation for the [robot.api](http://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.0.4/autodoc/robot.api.html) the note following note can be found:

> APIs related to the command line entry points are exposed directly via
>   the robot root package.

The referred documentation is [robot.run](http://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.0.4/autodoc/robot.html) or [robot.run_cli](http://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.0.4/autodoc/robot.html#robot.run.run_cli).

Comment: I tried executing using robot.run_cli but it's throwing the following exceptions. Have you ever come across this kind of issue?
`File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/robot/utils/encoding.py", line 93, in system_decode
    return string.decode(SYSTEM_ENCODING)
AttributeError: 'TestSuite' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: Although a fair question, this is really a new question about the implementation. My advice is to experiment with it and should you run into something you can't solve on your own create a new question specific to the situation you're in. Provide the code examples of the code you're working on, similar to the one in this question, and that will provide the basis for a good response.

Comment: The problem is that the `run_cli()` method not able to run the testsuite created by `TestSuite object of robot.api`